# Fortify Audit WorkBench scanning dtsx packages and returning 0 LOC

Tags: ssis, fortify

I do have SSIS packages which are in dtsx extension.
The dtsx packages basically contain XML codes.
The scan completed but with 0 LOC shown which is not what I want.
Basically my packages contains 70K LOC and it should show that number of LOC.

I have tried to save the files in xml extension and scanned the folder. The scan completed successfully, but 0 LOC(line of code) were shown.
I need the scan to show me the LOC as well.

Comment: I have no idea what a Fortify is or how it works. I do know something about SSIS. What is the problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: Fortify Audit WorkBench is a vulnerability testing software. It could be used to scan SSIS packages .It will report the security issues togethere with Line of codes. The issue that I am facing is that the Line of Code (LOC) shown is zero. what I am trying to ask around is how to resolve this issue by changing the configuration if possible or some other way.